# Issue on Scrolling the UITableView in iPhone.. data changes/ reloads when scrolls up/down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

I have implemented a tableview with a custom cell.

**1.Custom cell**
[image]

Custom cell having a label to display date and an UI Switch to set alarms.

My table view appears like like this when we switch on the uiswitches,
[image]

**2.Table view**

***`When user scrolls down the table view the bottom switches are turned off`***

[image]

Same problem when scrolls up.

[image]

why this problem happens ? and how to prevent it?

**Cell for row at index path method**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Note: I set the cell's Identifier property in Interface Builder to DemoTableViewCell.
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //To display custom cell with label and switch
    if(indexPath.row< [appDelegate.alarmsArray count])
    {
        ReminderCell *cell = (ReminderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];
        if (!cell)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        cell.reminderSwitch.tag = indexPath.row;

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [appDelegate.alarmsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.label.text = [dict objectForKey:@"string"];
//=========================================
        cell.reminderSwitch.on = NO;
//=========================================
        return cell;
    }


    //Add + button on the last row of uitableview cell..
    if(indexPath.row == [appDelegate.alarmsArray count])
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(114, 9.5, 33, 33); 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddNewRow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button ];
        return cell;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please include your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, where you set the switches on or off.

Comment: Are you storing the switches' values? Are you reusing cells? Are you using a subclass of UITableViewCell? Are you using the prepareForReuse method properly in that subclass?

Comment: Please post your code how you maintain state for On/Off of switches ?

Comment: please do not reuse cell if you are then use UISwitch in ON state

Comment: Sorry i did n't got the problem where it is in my cell for row at index path method?

Comment: You should check if the cell already has the '+' button before adding it to its contentView. And also remove it if the cell has not to have it.

Remember that when reusing cellViews you are using the same instances that previously might have been in other index paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In CustomCell Class Write function like this 

-(void)SetSwitchStatus:(NSInteger )stat
{
    if(stat == 0)
      //Set Switch off
    else
    //Set Switch on
} 


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    StoresCustomCell *cell =(StoresCustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StoresCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = StoreCell;
    }
    [cell SetSwitchStatus:[StatusArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

In ViewdidLoad Function Set 0 elements to all statusArr,,  StatusArr count = TableView rows Count

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)sender didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {

if([[StatusArr objectAtIndex:path.row] isEqualToString:@"0"])
   [StatusArr replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@"1"]
else
   [StatusArr replaceObjectAtIndex:path.row withObject:@"0"]
}
```

Comment: Sorry sir i did n't got the problem where it is in my cell for row at index path method?

Comment: <Rang Prasd> prasad.crr.786@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Most certanly you are not reusing the cells, then the switches are created each time a cell is displayed (and all the cell content too).
But be careful, because although you reuse the cell views, you will need to set the switch on/off property according to the value you want.
So your method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        /** THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED BY YOUR CONSTRUCTOR FROM NIB FILE **/
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    UISwitch *switch = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:SWITCH_TAG];
    switch.on = *is_on*;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I reused the cell.. cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease]; where is the problem

Comment: Sorry sir i did n't got the problem where it is in my cell for row at index path method?

Comment: This is not reusing a cell. This is preparing it to be able to be reused.
If you take a look at my code (or any other tableview example code), you will see that the cell first tries to be "extracted" with the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: message from the tableview. This will ask for a cell that has already been allocated but it is not used right now. If the returned cell was nil, then you need to create a new one the way you say. If an already cell is returned, it will appear configured as it was last time, and that is why you need to customize it both for new or reused instances.

Answer (score 1):

The problem will be in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: datasource method.  Remember that the cells are created and reused as the table scrolls, so the logic for each cell cannot make any assumptions about it's state.

You probably (you should) keep an array that has Alarms in it with time and a bool to indicate whether they are set...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"AlarmCell";  // your cell identifier goes here

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    CustomAlarmCell *alarmCell = (CustomAlarmCell *)cell;
    Alarm *alarm = [self.alarmArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    BOOL alarmIsSet = [alarm.isSet intValue];        // you should have an NSNumber 0 or 1 to indicate the alarm is set
    NSString *alarmTimeString = [alarm timeString];  // assume it has a date formatter and can render alarm time as string

    alarmCell.timeLabel.text = alarmTimeString;  
    alarmCell.isSetSwitch.on = alarmIsSet;

    return (UITableViewCell *)alarmCell;
}
```

Comment: reused the cell.. cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease]; but where is the problem

Comment: @Ranga, I think you are misunderstanding what reusing the cell means.  It means that the table doesn't have to create a new cell every time it scrolls, but that doesn't mean it keeps the same data in that cell -- you have to supply that as this answer points out.

Comment: Sorry sir i did n't got the problem where it is in my cell for row at index path method?